# pass corresponding Id to next view

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I need to make corresponding id available in JS file onclick of a button.

View :

In this view onclick of a button I am loading another view along with Javascript file which has angular code in  EverifyModule.js

```
<table>
 <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="emp in EmployeeInfo">
      <td>{{emp.name}}</td>
       <td>{{emp.hireDate}}</td>
 <!-- HERE on click of this link I need to make emp.empID avilable in the next view. --!>
       <td><a class="btn-sm btn-primary pull-right" href="javascript:void(0)"  onclick="LoadViewSelected('/EVerify/EVerify/EVerifySubmit', 'EVerifyModule', 'E-VerifySubmit');">E-Verify</a></td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

EVerifyModule.js

```
var EVerifyModule = angular.module('EVerifyModule', ['angularFileUpload', 'ui.bootstrap', 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);


    EVerifyModule.factory('EVerifyModuleService', ['$http', '$window', function ($http, $window) {

        return {

            GetEmployeeInfo: function (eId) {
                return $http({
                    url: '/api/EVerify/GetEmployeeInfo',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: eId
                });
            }
        };
    }]);


    EVerifyModule.controller('EVerifyController', ['$scope', '$http', '$compile', 'EVerifyModuleService', '$modal', '$timeout', function ($scope, $http, $compile, EVerifyModuleService, $modal, $timeout) {

// I need the empId from the previous view to be available here to pass for GetEmployeeInfo function. 

        EVerifyModuleService.GetEmployeeInfo(empId).then(function (response) {
            $scope.EmployeeInfo = response.data.Employees;
        });
```

EVerifyAPIController :

```
namespace MVC.EVerify.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/EVerify")]
    public class EVerifyAPIController : ApiController
    {
        #region GetEmployeeInfo

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("GetEmployeeInfo")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetEmployeeInfo(int empId)
        {
            List<EmployeeBO> employees = new List<EmployeeBO>();

                employee = await EmployeeBL.GetEmployeeInfo(empId);


            return Ok(new { Employee = employee });
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: what does `LoadViewSelected` do ?

Comment: It will load the view. in this case EverifySubmit view will be loaded.

Comment: why not pass the id to this method and pass that to your server when making the call so that it can be included in the response

Comment: an example please.